# How do I set API keys for Twitter in Meteor without using the GUI

Tags: twitter, meteor, meteor-accounts

How do I get rid of the configure button on the frontend from the {{>loginbuttons}} tag?

So far I have tried:

```
if (Meteor.isServer) {
 Meteor.startup(function(){

    Accounts.loginServiceConfiguration.remove({
        service: 'twitter'
    });

    Accounts.loginServiceConfiguration.insert({
        service:            'twitter',
        consumerKey:    'KEY',
        secret:                     'SECRET'
    });

 });
}
```

I can't find documentation for accounts-twitter, I can't seem to understand where Meteor packages code can be looked at.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the docs http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/meteor_loginwithexternalservice

First, add the service configuration package:

```
meteor add service-configuration
```

Then, in your app:

```
// first, remove configuration entry in case service is already configured
ServiceConfiguration.configurations.remove({
  service: "weibo"
});
ServiceConfiguration.configurations.insert({
  service: "weibo",
  clientId: "1292962797",
  loginStyle: "popup",
  secret: "75a730b58f5691de5522789070c319bc"
});
```

try

```
// first, remove configuration entry in case service is already configured
ServiceConfiguration.configurations.remove({
  service: "twitter"
});
ServiceConfiguration.configurations.insert({
  service: "twitter",
  consumerKey: "1292962797",
  loginStyle: "popup",
  secret: "keyyyyy"
});
```

Comment: Will try now. Where are the doc you refer to? I am honestly having a lot of trouble finding docs for meteor alone, the packages - I have no idea where to look for that. Coming from rails where everything is on github, this is very odd so far.

Comment: added link to official meteor docs, scroll down a bit to find about `service-configuration` or search for `service-configuration`.

Comment: By using `ServiceConfiguration.configurations.upsert` while startup, you can configure twitter login in one go.

Answer (score -2):

[**This Github repo**](https://github.com/themeteorchef/roll-your-own-authentication/), shows the use for Facebook, Twitter, Google and Github.

They behave the same, although args may be different.